# c#: icon associated with file extension

Tags: c#, file

In my application I create files with extension .mprj.

How can I assign an icon to this type of file?

Does appropriate .Net methods exist?

Comment: Would associating the file type to your program be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Related thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-the-current-executable-in-c-sharp

Comment: This has been thoroughly answered in the following [stack overflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993118/how-to-perform-shell-icon-embedding-in-visual-studio-2010/10415947#10415947). We've been using this implementation and it works great. It is also open source and integrates into MSBuild.

Comment: This has been thoroughly answered in the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993118/how-to-perform-shell-icon-embedding-in-visual-studio-2010/10415947#10415947

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to modify registry entries.
A code snippet how to do with c# can be found here:
http://mel-green.com/2009/04/c-set-file-type-association/

Comment: Remember that specified icon won't be visible for that extension until you close or kill any `Explorer.exe` process and then restart it! Rebooting Windows is another solution.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use InnoSetup to do that. You can assocaite a program with an extension to add icons, and to launch program when an users click on a file with this extension. (for example to open the file directly in the program like msoffice programs). When we click on an Excel file, Excel is launching and open this file. You can do the samething easy with InnoSetup and little code in main method to parse arguments.

With Innosetup you just add iIn the section [Setup]

```
ChangesAssociations=yes
```

And in the section [Registry]

```
Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".mpl"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{#MyAppName}"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#MyAppName}"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "Program {#MyAppName}"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#AppName}\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName},0"
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "{#AppName}\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\{#MyAppExeName}.EXE"" ""%1"""
```

---

More information in this [previous message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536030/inno-setup-file-association?answertab=active#tab-top)